# A coin Toss conditional probability question

Tags: probability, word-problem

I'm unable to solve this. Two players, A and B alternatively toss a fair coin (A tosses the coin first, then B tosses the coin, then A, then B and so on). The sequence of heads and tails is recorded. If there is a head followed by a tail (HT sub-sequence), the game ends and the person who tosses the tail wins. What is the probability that A wins the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by enumerating paths, but I find it easier to think about states and recurrences.

Step 1:  An easier question is to compute the probability that $A$ throws the first $T$? Call the answer $P_T$. To compute it consider the first toss.  Either $A$ throws a $T$ (an instant win) or $A$ throws an $H$ in which case we are back at the start of the game only now $B$ is the first to throw, hence the probability that $A$ wins from there is ($1-P_T$).  Thus:

$$P_T=\frac 12 1 + \frac 12 (1-P_T)\;\Rightarrow\;P_T=\frac 23$$

Step 2:  Back to your game.  Let $P$ be the answer you seek. look at the first two throws.  With equal probability the players get $HH$, $HT$, $TH$, and $TT$.  The first and third cases leave $A$ in the state we considered in Step 1.  The second is a loss.  The fourth just gets back to the initial state.  Thus:

$$P=\frac 14\;\left(\frac 23 +0+\frac23+P\right)\;\Rightarrow\;P=\frac49$$

Comment: To make this elegant answer even more elegant, you could do step $2$ in the same style as step $1$: $A$ throws $H$ or $T$; $B$ wins with probability $P_T$ in the first case and $P$ in the second, so

$$
P=1-\frac12(P_T+P) \;\Rightarrow\;\frac32P=\frac23\;\Rightarrow\;P=\frac49\;.
$$

Comment: @joriki Thanks!  As yet a third variant:  A has two ways of winning.  Either A throws the first $H$ (prob = $\frac 23$ and then also throws the next $T$ despite starting second (prob = $\frac 13$), or $B$ throws the first $H$ ($\frac 13$) and then $A$ throws the next $T$ ($\frac 23$), hence $$P=\frac 23\,\frac 13\;+\;\frac 13\,\frac 23=\frac 49$$

Comment: @lulu Thank you. However, can I just ask what you mean by "The first and third cases leave A in the state we considered in Step 1."? I can't see how $HH$ leaves A in the same state as Step 1.

Comment: Sure.  Given that they have thrown $HH$ (or $TH$ for that matter) then the winner will now be the first player to throw a $T$, just as in Step 1.  As $A$ is the first to throw (in these two scenarios) we are exactly in the world contemplated by Step 1.  (Note:  the two other variants described in the comments here both avoid this line of reasoning, may give a different perspective on things).

Comment: @lulu So, am I right in thinking that in the Step 1 $P_{T}$ represents the probability $A$ wins if he throws the first tail?

Comment: @Jojo  Correct.  By definition, $P_T$ is the probability that $A$ throws the first $T$ assuming $A$ is the first to throw.  (Note:  by symmetry, $P_H$, the probability that $A$ throws the first $H$ has the same value).

Comment: @Jojo If you want an exercise, generalize these arguments to deal with unfair coins.  That is, suppose we have a weighted coin, that comes up $H$ with probability $\phi$ and answer all the questions over again.  It's not much harder!

Comment: @Jojo  On rethinking, I fear I may have misunderstood your most recent comment.  $P_T$ is not the probability that $A$ wins your original game (even with contingencies).  My Step 1 introduces a new, simpler, game in which the object is simply to throw the first $T$.  That's a good warm up exercise in any case, though in this case it turns out to be directly useful in the solution to the main question.

Comment: @lulu Thanks! May I ask one further question. With regards to Step 2, for the $TH$ scenario. Isn't the probability $A$ wins the probability he gets a 2nd tail and not the first tail? I am just wondering how the logic from step 1 was applied to this scenario.

Comment: @Jojo  The probability that $A$ wins from the $TH$ scenario is the probability that $A$ throws the NEXT $T$.  That leaves us in Step 1, again.  Doesn't matter what came before.  The probability that $A$ throws the next $T$, given that $A$ gets to go first, is $P_T$ again.